# Inner join + where ORACLE

Tags: sql, oracle

im struggling on this qwery. Im new in oracle and i got a question about it.

Im trying to use inner join with alias to find something.

Theres what i got:

```
SELECT F.Nome, C.Num_Fatura, C.Valor_total
from cliente AS F INNER JOIN fatura AS C USING(cod_cliente) AND F.localidade = 'Lisboa';
```

I dont know what i'm doing wrong, since my oracle is showing my this error code:

> ORA-00933: SQL command not properly terminated

Thank you.

Comment: write filter condition in where clause

Comment: In an Oracle SQL query, you can give aliases to columns and to tables. When you alias a column, you can use the keyword AS for clarity; it is not mandatory, but it is allowed. However, for **table** aliases, the keyword AS is **not allowed**. Follow the table name with the table alias, without the word AS. Then, after you fix that, you will find the second error, mentioned in the Comment above this one and also in the solution posted by Jacob Goldhirsch. Jacob's solution corrected both mistakes, but he only explained the second one.

Answer (score 1):

You can't have a filter expression in a using clause
You have to write it in a where

```
SELECT F.Nome, C.Num_Fatura, C.Valor_total 
FROM cliente F INNER JOIN
     fatura C
     USING (cod_cliente) 
WHERE F.localidade = 'Lisboa'
```